# Headlights not working in 2006 Mazda6

Tags: mazda

I have a 2006 Mazda6, and the headlights in it have not been working since I replaced the alternator.  But the high beams work just fine.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Are the bulbs ok?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the alternator replacement has introduced an open in the low-beam circuitry, but there are other potential root causes.

Here's a way to help you rule out other possibilities:

- ***faulty light switch***

  Find the relay labelled "HEAD RELAY" in the image below. Without removing it, put your hand on the relay and have someone cycle the low-beam switch on/off from the interior. If you can feel/hear the relay click, you know that the relay is receiving signal from the light switch and can rule this out.

[image: fuse box]

- ***blown low-beam fuses***

  There are 15 A fuses right next to the headlamp relay. Test/inspect these to make sure that they are not blown.

---

If the above two possibilities are ruled out, you should be able to confirm the open circuit with a multimeter:

- pull out the headlamp relay
- set the multimeter to voltage mode
- probe the fuse box where relay terminals 30 and 87 are supposed to connect. A zero voltage reading would confirm the circuit open
- don't forget to reinstall the headlamp relay

Comment: [Source for the image](http://forum.mazda6club.com/3-0l-v6/258158-final-impacts-running-list-links-help-solve-issues-5.html)

Comment: @zaid I don't think probing 30 and 87 with the meter set to resistance would be a good idea.  There will be 12v across those terminals if there is no break in the wiring.  The test should be done with the meter set to voltage.  Do you agree?

Comment: @HandyHowie I was under the impression that resistance mode is similar to voltage mode. If it isn't, I will change it. Definitely don't want it to be in current mode, that's for sure

Comment: @zaid Resistance mode puts power through the circuit it is testing.  Current mode would be OK as long as the meter was able to read the current drawn by the 2 lamps - at least a 10 amp range on the meter.  Anything less would blow the meter.

Comment: @HandyHowie Agreed. I know some mechanics would just bridge the terminals with a copper wire to see if the headlights come on, but I wouldn't recommend it for safety reasons.